# use async await to build api

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I have writen aan Node api with express. In this api I am getting some data from database processing that and sending the final data as api payload.

Here is my code..

```
exports.getAllAco =  (req, res) => {
    let acoList = [], i = 0;

    let condaions = {
        deleted: 0,
    }

    let attributes = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'type', 'phone', 'gender', 'main_sys_id', 'avatar', 'in_service', 'created_by']
    Methods.getAllData(User, condaions, attributes).then((userList) => {
            userList.map( user => {
                i = i + 1;
                if (user.dataValues.type == 'aco') {
                    let condations = {
                        aquisition_member_id: user.dataValues.id,
                        deleted: 0
                    }

                    Methods.getDetailsFromTwoAssociateTable(condations, Task, DetailTask).then(tasks => {
                        let x = {
                            user: user,
                            tasks: tasks
                        }

                        x.user.dataValues.totalTask = tasks.length;

                        let index = 0;

                        x.user.dataValues.userTotalAssigned = 0, x.user.dataValues.userTotalCalled = 0, x.user.dataValues.userTotalConverted = 0, x.user.dataValues.userTotalRejected = 0;

                        tasks.map(v=>{
                            x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalAssignedCustomer = v.dataValues.detail_tasks.length;
                            x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalCalled = 0;
                            x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalConverted = 0;
                            x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalRejected = 0;
                            v.dataValues.detail_tasks.map(detail_task=>{

                                 x.user.dataValues.userTotalAssigned += 1;

                                if(detail_task.dataValues.phone_call_status == 'called' ){
                                    x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalCalled += 1;
                                    x.user.dataValues.userTotalCalled +=1;
                                }

                                else if(detail_task.dataValues.phone_call_status == 'confirmed'){
                                    x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalConverted +=1;
                                    x.user.dataValues.userTotalConverted += 1;
                                }

                                else{
                                    x.user.dataValues.userTotalRejected += 1;
                                    x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalRejected += 1;
                                }
                            })
                            index=index+1;
                        })

                        // x.user.dataValues.totalAssigned = totalAssigned;

                        acoList.push(x)                           
                    })
                }
            })
            return acoList;
    }).then(acoList=>{
       setTimeout(() => {
        Methods.successResponse(req, res, acoList)
       }, 2000);
    }).catch((error) => {
        ErrorResMethods.errorResponse(req, res, error);
    })
}
```

to send the actual result I have to wait for two second other wise the response is empty.

How can I implement that with async/await.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should do the work.

```
exports.getAllAco = async (req, res) => {
  let i = 0;

  const condaions = {
    "deleted": 0
  };

  const attributes = ["id", "name", "email", "type", "phone", "gender", "main_sys_id", "avatar", "in_service", "created_by"];
  const userList = await Methods.getAllData(User, condaions, attributes);
  const acoList = await Promise.all(userList.map(async user => {
    i += 1;
    if (user.dataValues.type == "aco") {
      const condations = {
        "aquisition_member_id": user.dataValues.id,
        "deleted": 0
      };

      const tasks = await Methods.getDetailsFromTwoAssociateTable(condations, Task, DetailTask);
      const x = {
        "user": user,
        "tasks": tasks
      };

      x.user.dataValues.totalTask = tasks.length;

      let index = 0;

      x.user.dataValues.userTotalAssigned = 0, x.user.dataValues.userTotalCalled = 0, x.user.dataValues.userTotalConverted = 0, x.user.dataValues.userTotalRejected = 0;

      tasks.forEach(v => {
        x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalAssignedCustomer = v.dataValues.detail_tasks.length;
        x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalCalled = 0;
        x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalConverted = 0;
        x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalRejected = 0;
        v.dataValues.detail_tasks.map(detail_task => {

          x.user.dataValues.userTotalAssigned += 1;

          if (detail_task.dataValues.phone_call_status == "called") {
            x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalCalled += 1;
            x.user.dataValues.userTotalCalled += 1;
          } else if (detail_task.dataValues.phone_call_status == "confirmed") {
            x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalConverted += 1;
            x.user.dataValues.userTotalConverted += 1;
          } else {
            x.user.dataValues.userTotalRejected += 1;
            x.tasks[index].dataValues.totalRejected += 1;
          }
        });
        index += 1;
      });
      return x;
    }
  })
  Methods.successResponse(req, res, acoList);
```

Comment: why setTimeout function still ?

Comment: I dont know the intent of this. If you dont need it, you could just remove. as your call is now properly async. Earlier it wasn;t

Comment: and for catching the error, you could wrap the whole code in `try..catch`

Comment: there have some error can you please check your answer ?

Comment: my answer was to give you an idea about how it can be done. If you are faicng error, please mention here or try to figure out what the cause could be